# Does every $(\mathfrak{g}, K)$-module have a $K$-finite globalisation?

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a real reductive group and $K$ a maximal compact subgroup of $G$. If $V_0$ is a $(\mathfrak{g},K)$-module, assumed admissible if necessary, does there exist a continuous representation $(\pi,V)$ of $G$ that is $K$-finite (i.e. every vector $v\in V$ is $K$-finite)?